# Cross compiling qml app and mouse focus issue

Tags: qt, qml, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi3

When I cross compile my qml app on raspberry3 , the mouse cursor disables and touch screen of the program works well .

But when I run the program on raspberry by command line , as I touch the screen ,
mouse cursor moves on app , and It seems that every movements and actions of mouse in the program , happens outside the program on the screen of raspberry too!!!

(all movements , clicks and everything!)

But I want the focus of the mouse be disabled on the screen of rasp when I run the program on it; like the situation of cross compiling the program on rasp.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable mouse cursor in your application by using this line in your main.cpp

```
QGuiApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::BlankCursor);
```

This will permanently disable mouse cursor inside your app but it will be appear outside it.